# Create thread with member function pointer

Tags: c++, multithreading, member-functions

I am trying to create a `std::thread` with a pointer to member function that takes 1 arguments and returns `void`.

When I create member function `sample1()`, it is OK. But I do not now how to create a thread with `sample2()`.

```cpp
class ClassName
{
public:
    void handle();
private:
    void sample1(size_t t1);
    void (*sample2)(size_t t2);
};

ClassName::handle()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> tasks{SIZE};
    for (size_t i = 0; i<SIZE; ++i){
        tasks.emplace_back(&MapReduce::sample1, std::ref(*this), std::ref(i));
        // next line make error
        // tasks.emplace_back(&MapReduce::sample2, std::ref(*this), std::ref(i));   
    }
}
```

When I trying to create the thread:

```cpp
emplace_back(&MapReduce::sample2, std::ref(*this), std::ref(i))
```

It report an error:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/10.2.0/thread:136:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
```

Comment: `emplace_back()` is not defined, so I doubt you get an error there. Please, take a step back and extract a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it mean tasks.emplace_back()

Comment: `sample2` is a variable that just happens to be a pointer to function from `size_t`. `sample1` is a member function - two completely dufferent things. Also you need to fill `sample2` somehow else it is UB.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need `std::ref(*this)` as the second argument. Plain `this` will suffice. Also for the third argument, `std::ref(i)` is not needed just pass plain `i`. You only need `std::ref` if the thread function itself wants its arguments as (non-constant) references.

Comment: And I'm surprised that `std::vector<std::thread> tasks{SIZE};` works, as the use of curly-braces `{}` should invoke the `std::initializer_list` constructor.

Comment: You should review the detailed explanation in your textbook why `this` must be the first parameter when invoking `sample1`. Once you understand the explanation you should understand what needs to be done with `sample2`.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a member function pointer here? (as in it is handed around from somewhere else). Because in the provided example, I would just use a lambda and be done with it instead.

Comment: My recommendation: wrap the call in a lambda that doesn't need arguments. Much easier to work with